# Meaning of JVM exit code 10

Tags: java, jvm, exit-code

I got the below message when the JVM exited:

```
JVM process exited with a code of 10
```

What is the meaning of exit code 10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **JVM** yields the exit code specified by the program with `System.exit(code).`

If the JVM crashed it's OS specific what the exit code could mean

Comment: By convention, positive numbers tend to indicate that the program couldn't do exactly what it was that you asked it to do, or that something unusual happened while it was trying to do it. However this isn't universally true. A program can use exit codes to indicate whatever they want them to mean. So a program could offer a list of choices and set the exit code to indicate which choice was selected. Exit code 10 could indicate that the user selected the 10th (or even 11th) option...