# What causes JVM exit code 10?

Tags: java, jvm, crash, exit

An Eclipse RCP aplication running on Mac OS X 10 is crashing with java exit code 10. What does this mean, and what might be a possible cause?

Additional information:
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.5.0_20
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=carbon, NL=fi_FI
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws carbon

-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xms650m
-Xbatch

Some more information from a .crash file:

```
Process:         java [2215]
Path:            /usr/bin/java
Identifier:      java
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  eclipse [2214]

Date/Time:       2009-11-12 13:19:45.263 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)
Report Version:  6
Anonymous UUID:  B2FA3949-E261-4B4E-A924-316E6C17CD3E

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000004caeb160
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:

Java information:
  Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_20-141 mixed mode)
  Virtual Machine version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_20-141) for   macosx-x86,      built on Aug 13 2009 10:28:19 by root with gcc 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)
 Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=0x96d903cd
```

And here is some of the thread 0 trace:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   com.apple.QD                    0x96d903cd _SetDstBits32BGRA + 8
1   com.apple.QD                    0x96d83c55 DevRgn + 301
2   com.apple.QD                    0x96d83a65 StdRgn + 671
3   com.apple.QD                    0x96d837c0 CallRgn + 50
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9512d356 MyDrawingProc + 101
5   com.apple.QD                    0x96db1569 CommonDeviceLoop + 918
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9512d3fc InvertMyRegion + 164
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9512d8dc ShowDragHilite + 431
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95172fa9      CTextensionDrag::ShowDragFeedBack(TCharOffset, OpaqueDragRef*, unsigned char) + 329
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9517318d CTextensionDrag::DragInWindow(OpaqueDragRef*, unsigned char) + 331
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x951731f4 CTextensionDrag::DragTracking(short, OpaqueDragRef*, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 80
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x951874b3 OpaqueTXNObject::DragTracking(short, OpaqueDragRef*, unsigned char) + 119
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x951874f4 CEasyTextDrag::ClientDragTracking(short, OpaqueDragRef*, unsigned char) + 56
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95173eaa CTextensionDrag::HIDragWithin(OpaqueDragRef*) + 46
```

User was dragging and dropping items to the application, it looks like it might be some native library problem with this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994752/java-exit-code-meaning

Comment: I don't think it's a dup. The referenced answer is a bit facetious.

Answer (score 0):

What version of java are you using, and with what settings?
[This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg20205.html) reports a similar crash, and it seems to be linked to the JVM version, and also to settings like:

```
-vmargs -Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

try at least to specify the VM, as in this [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590).

(Note: the so-called ["dup" SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994752/java-exit-code-meaning) mentioned in the comment is only there to tell you the exit code is program-specific or OS-specific, which do not you tell much.
And I am not aware of eclipse-specific exit codes)

Comment: Thanks, I've added more info now to the original comment.

Answer (score 0):

The exit code is almost certainly coming from the RCP application - not the JVM itself - so you'll need to consult the application docs or code to find out what it means.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure it's not coming from our own application code so it must be coming from the RCP plaform, does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this was eclipse running on  Mac OSX the error code probably means that there is a corrupt cache entry.  This is a bug with the Apple implementation.  I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of eclipse and jvm.  Just to be sure, can you post what the system console and crash.logs show when this happens?

Comment: It was not eclipse IDE but an eclipse RCP based app. Our log4j logs showed no errors/exceptions. Where would the crash logs be? I do not have direct access to the computer myself, I'd have to request the files

Comment: The metadata/.log file has no exceptions or stack traces at the time of the crash.